# How to send a message to a thread (reply) using a Bot Framework SDK 4.18 Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Scenario:-

1. User A -> Types a message in Teams App (bot)
2. Now Bot has to reply to the same thread that user A has started in Teams App (bot)

I am able to send a new message in the Teams App (bot) - Not expected
[image: Not Expected]

The bot needs to reply to the same thread the user started -  Expected
[image: Expected]

Did not find any reply method in the below documentation.. continueConversation creates a new message.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/turncontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#botbuilder-core-turncontext-getmentions&preserve-view=true

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics

Comment: Could you please refer the below thread for this issue: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/how-to-send-a-message-to-a-thread-reply-using-botbuilder-4-0-sdk/m-p/3716974#M7205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bot cannot give the reply to the same thread that user started. This is by design behaviour.

Bot can reply to an existing message but it looks new message not like reply, call [ReplyToActivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.connector.conversationsextensions.replytoactivityasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0#Microsoft_Bot_Connector_ConversationsExtensions_ReplyToActivityAsync_Microsoft_Bot_Connector_IConversations_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Bot_Connector_Activity_System_Threading_CancellationToken_&preserve-view=true) in .NET or [session.send](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/TurnContext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest&viewFallbackFrom=botbuilder-ts-3.0#sendactivities&preserve-view=true) in Node.js. The Bot Builder SDK handles all the details.

If you choose to use the REST API, you can also call the /v3/conversations/{conversationId}/activities/{activityId} endpoint.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-co...

If you wish you can suggest this feature on - [Microsoft Teams · Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Comment: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/e63a7768-ed97-ed11-a81b-6045bdaf6a9e - Feature requested..